# How to do a subquery in doctrine and get the result hydrated to an object?

Tags: doctrine, subquery, group-concat

I want to do a somewhat complex query in doctrine, namely an inner join with a subquery with a group_concat.

See the query in plain SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM kinderen k
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT i.kindid, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.periode) as periodes
  FROM inschrijvingen i
  INNER JOIN activiteiten a ON i.activiteitid=a.id
  GROUP BY i.kindid
) p
ON k.kindid=p.kindid;
```

1) How can I do this in doctrine? In other words how can I translate this regular sql into dql?

2) I would like the extra property (periodes) to be accessible in the resulting Kinderen object. I suspect that this is default behavior for doctrine?

I can't find the solution when I read through the docs and google.

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is available in Doctrine 2 as a "fetch join" but not sure if it exists for 1.2.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language/en

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324101/doctrine-regular-vs-fetch-join
Regular vs fetch seems only to be a matter of performance. My main question is how to translate the regular sql into dql, I'll update my question. Thanx.

Comment: I see... I was thrown off by the hydration bit. Does it have to be DQL? See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774947/using-raw-sql-with-doctrine/2777020 ... not sure what the execution methods offer for hydrating everything. When I need to bypass DQL occassionally, I always for go for array data.

Comment: Thanks for the link.
But... I have several functions processing the result and those expect an object. Of course I can rewrite them, but it would be nice to keep it object-orientated. I use Zend + Doctrine.

Comment: Did you take a look at the "Doctrine_Connection" options here: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/api ... ? You might find something there.

Comment: The doctrine links are broken.